# Running scripts in deployment manager

Tags: scripting, google-deployment-manager

How do I run script along side a cluster instance that I am creating for configuring sql proxy using Google Deployment Manager ?

Comment: Hello, can you rephrase your question? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I meant how do I run a start up script on a Kubernetes cluster ? I saw for a compute instance we run it in their metadata. Is it the same way for a cluster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Startup scripts are not allowed to be specified for GKE nodes. From https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/v1/NodeConfig:

Additionally, to avoid ambiguity, keys must not conflict with any other metadata keys for the project or be one of the four reserved keys: "instance-template", "kube-env", "startup-script", and "user-data"

Take a look at https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/startup-script for a way to replace the functionality of startup scripts with a daemonset.